Android Studio Gradle Build Error: Could not find dependencies
I recently updated Android Studio to Koala 2024.1.2.
Gradle was also updated to 8.10.1.
Plugins were also updated to 8.6.0.
Now, during a project build 3 dependencies cannot be found:
 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
 'com.github.anastr:rulerview:1.1.0'
 'me.anwarshahriar:calligrapher:1.0'

My settings.gradle:
 pluginManagement {
     repositories {
          gradlePluginPortal()
          google()
         mavenCentral()
         maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
     }
 }
 dependencyResolutionManagement {
     repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
     repositories {
         google()
         mavenCentral()
         maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
     }
 }

My dependencies in build.gradle:
 dependencies {
     implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0'
     implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0'
     implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
     testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
     androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.2.1'
     androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.6.1'
     implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     implementation 'com.amulyakhare:com.amulyakhare.textdrawable:1.0.1'
     implementation 'com.github.anastr:rulerview:1.1.0'
     implementation 'me.anwarshahriar:calligrapher:1.0'
 }

Things I've tried:

Invalidate Caches and Restart
Clean Build
Increasing org.gradle.jvmargs memory in gradle.properties
Downloading .jar files from "https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-jar-plugin"
with
"https://jar-download.com/online-maven-download-tool.php"
However, with all missing libraries above, I would get a Download Error. Any other library that I do not need work.
Manually creating missing libraries .jar files from github.

I was unsuccessful in creating .jar files due to old versions. Tried installing Android Studio Bumblebee but it seems older gradle or jdk files are no longer supported.
I understand that jcenter repository is no longer supported and perhaps this is why I'm getting this error.
Is there anything I can try? Is this a known issue?
Any help or ideas would be much appreciated.

it happened due to jcenter(), as it is no longer supported now. You can use https://jitpack.io/ to find a suitable replacement for the deprecated library by entering git link or the second solution is to add library as a module in your project and manually update it.

Thank you! That is exactly what I was missing. Needed to go to https://jitpack.io/, paste old git link, and find a suitable replacement, usually first one. Replacement dependencies use different format.
