Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.TypedResolveException: Couldn't resolve files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'
I am encountering issues resolving dependencies while trying to build my Android project. Here are the details of my project configuration:
Project build.gradle:
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.7.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

tasks.register('clean', Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

App build.gradle:
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 35

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.welborn.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 35
        versionCode 1
        versionName "V1.1.14 Beta"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("..//certificates/upload_keystore.jks")
            storePassword 'abc12345'
            keyAlias 'upload'
            keyPassword 'abc12345'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }

    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all {
            outputFileName = "App Version_${defaultConfig.versionName}.apk"
        }
    }

    android.buildFeatures.buildConfig = true
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0'
    implementation 'com.github.JessYanCoding:AndroidAutoSize:v1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.11.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.11.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.11.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.21'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.12.0'
    implementation 'com.baoyz.swipemenulistview:library:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.16.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.16.0'
    implementation 'com.tbruyelle.rxpermissions2:rxpermissions:0.9.5@aar'
    implementation 'cn.carbswang.android:NumberPickerView:1.2.0'
}

Gradle Wrapper properties:
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.9-bin.zip
networkTimeout=10000
validateDistributionUrl=true
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists

Problem:
When trying to build the project with compileSdkVersion 35, I encounter the following errors:
Failed to resolve: com.baoyz.swipemenulistview:library:1.3.0
Failed to resolve: com.tbruyelle.rxpermissions2:rxpermissions:0.9.5
Failed to resolve: cn.carbswang.android:NumberPickerView:1.2.0

I have tried several things, including:
Changing the Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) version and Gradle version.
Reverting the target SDK to 33 works fine, but moving to 35 causes these dependency resolution issues.
Downloading the latest Android Studio.
The errors eventually lead to:
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.TypedResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath.

`What I’ve Tried:
Reverting to AGP 7.4.2 and Gradle version 8.9.
Checking the repository URLs (both jitpack.io, google(), and mavenCentral()).
Verified the dependencies for potential version issues.
Any help on how to resolve these dependency issues with targetSdkVersion 35 would be greatly appreciated.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/79000287/7874746
Check if this helps for first and third library and for second you need to update version to latest
